# How strides help in traversing an array in numpy?

Tags: numpy, memory, numpy-ndarray, stride

```
arr = np.arange(16).reshape((2, 2, 4))

arr.strides
(32, 16, 4)
```

So, I believe from my knowledge that in memory it would be something like the image below.
The strides are marked along with the axis (on the arrows).

[image: Initial stacking in memory block]

And this is what I think I have after transposing one of the axes using the command:

```
arr.transpose((1, 0, 2))
```

[image: After transposing i.e. switching 2 of the axes]

I understand there is no changes in the memory block but I am not able to understand how exactly does the strides help in traversing the array in the memory block to produce the expected array. (does it traverse the elements in different axes in reverse order?)

```
[[[ 0  1  2  3]
[ 4  5  6  7]] 
[[ 8  9 10 11]
[12 13 14 15]]]
```

I tried going through the official numpy code in C to understand, but I was not able to understand the same.

It would be great if somebody could just provide the explanation in a simpler way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numpy always iterate through the axis from the biggest one to the smallest one (ie. decreasing order) unless explicitly ask for (eg. with the `axis` parameter). Thus, in your example, it first read the item of the view at the offset 0 in memory, then add the stride of the axis 2 (4 here) and read the next item and so on until the end of the axis is reached. It then add the stride of the axis 1 once and repeat the previous loop again, and so on with other axis.

The internal Numpy C code behave like this:

```c
// Numpy array are not strongly typed internally.
// The raw memory buffer is always contiguous.
char* data = view.rawData;

const size_t iStride = view.stride[0];
const size_t jStride = view.stride[1];
const size_t kStride = view.stride[2];

for(int i=0 ; i<view.shape[0] ; ++i) {
    for(int j=0 ; j<view.shape[1] ; ++j) {
        for(int k=0 ; k<view.shape[2] ; ++k) {
            // Compute the offset from the view strides
            const size_t offset = iStride * i + jStride * j + kStride * k;

            // Extract an item at the memory offset
            Type item = (Type*)(data + offset);

            // Do something with item here (eg. print it)
        }
    }
}
```

When you apply a transposition, Numpy change the stride so that `iStride` and `jStride` are swapped. It also update the shape (`view.shape[0]` and `view.shape[1]` are swapped too). The code will **execute as if the two loops are swapped** except the memory accesses will be less efficient because they are less *contiguous*. Here is an example:

```py
arr = np.arange(16).reshape((2, 2, 4))
arr.strides   # (32, 16, 4)
view = arr.transpose((1, 0, 2))
view.strides  # (16, 32, 4)  <--  note that 16 and 32 have been swapped
```

Note that the strides are in **bytes** (and not a number of items).

Comment: Thanks a lot! This has helped me clear my doubt.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience working through the C code is too much work.  Simply finding the relevant function(s) is the hardest part.  `strides` work the same regardless of dimensions or 'transpose'.

Start with something simpler, like a (2,3) array, whose transposed strides will be (8,24).  Imagine stepping through the flat [0,1,2...].

Sample array, with 1 byte size so the sequential stride will be just 1

```
In [635]: x=np.arange(6,dtype='uint8')
In [636]: x
Out[636]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], dtype=uint8)
In [637]: x.strides
Out[637]: (1,)
```

Now reshape it:

```
In [638]: y=x.reshape(2,3)
In [639]: y
Out[639]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]], dtype=uint8)
In [640]: y.strides
Out[640]: (3, 1)
```

To go across columns we still just step by 1 through the shared `x` data-buffer.  To go down, we step the 3, 0 to 3, 2 to 5.

```
In [641]: z = y.transpose()
In [642]: z
Out[642]: 
array([[0, 3],
       [1, 4],
       [2, 5]], dtype=uint8)
In [643]: z.strides
Out[643]: (1, 3)
```

Now to go down we step by 1, to go across step by 3.

But then you deduced the same with the images (which officially we're supposed to ignore :)  )

So what's your problem?  If you have problems going through some particular `C` code, you need to show it, or at least reference it.

There are lots of ways of traversing an array.  For flatiter strides doesn't matter, it just goes through the databuffer one item at a time.

But if for example we iterate on the first dimension,

```
In [687]: for i in y:print(i)
[0 1 2]
[3 4 5]
```

steps by 3 to fetch the next row.

```
In [688]: for i in z:print(i)
[0 3]
[1 4]
[2 5]
```

while this steps by 1.

Comment: I am sorry I understand that I should also have embedded the link to the C code. This time I have been able to get my doubt resolved. Thanks for the help!